# Logarithm in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to do a box plot, and for that I am using the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("Data_P64.txt", header=None, names=["val"])
df["cat"] = np.tile(np.repeat(["A", "B", "C"], 5), 7)
df["num1_5_10"] = np.repeat([1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 15)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val", hue="cat", zorder=0.9, dodge=False)
#add the lines connecting the median values
sns.pointplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val", hue="cat", estimator=np.median, ci=None, markers="None", ax=ax)


#remove duplicate entries, setting the legend outside the graph, new title
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:3], labels[:3], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title="C++ for the win")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But what I want to do is that for Y-axis I want to take the `logarithm` of the Y values. How to do this here?

Is this the right way?

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data_P64.txt", header=None, names=["val"])
df["cat"] = np.tile(np.repeat(["A", "B", "C"], 5), 7)
df["num1_5_10"] = np.repeat([1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 15)

df['val_log'] = np.log2(df['val'].values)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val_log", hue="cat", zorder=0.9, dodge=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create another column called val_log by:

```
df['val_log'] = np.log(df['val'].values)
```

and create the plot:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val_log", hue="cat", zorder=0.9, dodge=False)
```

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("Data_P64.txt", header=None, names=["val"])`
`df["cat"] = np.tile(np.repeat(["A", "B", "C"], 5), 7)`
`df["num1_5_10"] = np.repeat([1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 15)`

`df['val_log'] = np.log(df['val'].values)`

is this the right way?

Comment: I have edited the question, do check now..
is this the right way?